# Signalr server messages to client cancelled (specific clients only)

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I use `signalR` to display currently connected users. Some clients are failing to see the connected clients because the server to client connection is being cancelled by the client as shown below:

[image]

Below is my `js` code:

```
        var progressNotifier = $.connection.activeConnectionsHub;
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            progressNotifier.server.showActiveConnections();

                   // code here
        });

        // client-side sendMessage function that will be called from the server-side
        progressNotifier.client.addConnections = function (param) {
                // code here never gets called
       }
```

This only happens on some client browsers.

I tried disabling antivirus, firewall, malware etc. But it is still not working.

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: Was there a `connect` request? Does it happen only for webSockets?

Comment: @Pawel, there is a connect request and immidiately after the websockets is aborted

Comment: What do you mean by "websockets"? The connect request starts the actual websocket so I don't know how you would see it before connect. I would recommend turning on logging (as per https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#javascript) and handling fail() in addition to done() after start to see what error you got if any.